# What is the url for creating a defect in rally using jsonp

Tags: jsonp, rally

My jsonp ajax request looks like this, but its not working. My guess is that the url is not correct. This url works fine which is to get a defect description:

(`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/defect.js?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/workspace/108748843&query=&start=1&pagesize=20`)

But the following is not working with the url which is to create a defect:

(`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/defect/create.js`)

```
var request = $.ajax({
          url: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/defect/create.js",
          data: { 'Defect': defectData },
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonp: 'jsonp',
          username: "<username>",
          password: "<pass>",
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
              console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using either of Rally's App SDK's?  They make it easy to do I/O with Rally's web services without you having to know the details of jsonp vs. ajax.  They also contain some really nice ui components for displaying data from Rally.

1.x:
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/rally-data-source

2.x preview:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p3/doc/#!/guide/appsdk_20_data_models
https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p3/doc/#!/guide/appsdk_20_data_stores